# eclipse 4.3 RCP product is not working

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I am facing a major issue in eclipse rcp. I created an application in eclipse rcp
and created a product file and run the application. It works fine as expected.
After that I exported the my application to a product. After that I run the eclipse, it does not work as expected. when my application is started, a view with
one composite which is having some text fields supposed to appear. But it does not appear. Everything is working before exporting to eclipse product.
I am using eclipse 4.3.

Aslo I checked the build configuration and checked that everything is added to
the build.properties. It is available.

I suspect it is because of any cache or something like that? or what else I can give a try in order to make it work? 
What is the the way to clean the cache? I used -clean command while launching the eclipse.

> ./eclipse -clean

Comment: Have you checked, that all the dependencies you needed were exported to your application? My most common fault is, to add something to the Run Config instead of the product file. And when I build my application, I lack a plugin. Do you get any errors in your applications log file?

Comment: Hi Calon, thanks for the message.  I checked it and found all the dependencies are available. Also could not see any error information in the log. so it has been very difficult to find out the issue.Neither showing any error nor working.

Comment: If you are using a perspective you may need to do a Reset Perspective.